# Limiting IPs with ACL rules in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-vpc

There are two IP addresses (172.31.42.243 and 172.31.19.188) that are hitting my site in AWS (Beanstalk hosted) repeatedly with garbage requests.

I have tried to block them using ACL deny rules. If I add only one I'm still able to hit my site. If I add both then I'm not able to hit my site.

Both the deny rules are using /32 for the CIDR notation and the deny rules I added are lower numbers than the default allow all rule. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are you running ? What are you behind ?

Comment: It is an IIS hosted web site created using a load balanced Elastic Beanstalk

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those aren't the IP addresses of the machines that are attacking you; those are the internal IP addresses of your ELB. That's also why you can't access your site after blocking them - no one can!

You need to look at the access logs on the ELB, not on your application server, to determine which IP address(es) are attacking you. You can configure access logging on your ELB on the "Description" tab, under "Attributes".

Comment: I will configure the access logs, thanks for the suggestion.  I thought internal IP addresses would look like 10.x.x.x?

Comment: Internal IP addresses aren't limited to the 10.x.x.x range. You need to log into your VPC console and look at what IP ranges your VPC is setup to use.

Comment: Per Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network), private IP addresses can be in three ranges: 10.0.0.0 – 10.255.255.255, 172.16.0.0 – 172.31.255.255, or 192.168.0.0 – 192.168.255.255. ELB seems to use the second range.

Comment: ELB internal addresses in VPC will always be within the VPC CIDR. When you configure an ELB, you put it on one or more subnets, and it picks up at least one address from each of those subnets (more, when it scales up). You can actually find the virtual NIC cards of the ELBs in the left side menu of the EC2 console, under Network Interfaces.   VPCs are not actually constrained to use RFC-1918 but to provision one using a different network wouldn't be a good idea except in rare cases.